# materializecss modal background opacity remains

Tags: angularjs, materialize

After click button or link in modal window, modal window is closed and opacity background remains. By blocking all the space.
If before pressing the button causes the window, refresh the page, then the problem does not occur. Materialize version: '0.97.6'

```
<button ng-click="delete(item)" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Yes</button>
$scope.delete = function() { $state.go('table'); };
```

The background:

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: [link](https://whispering-hamlet-99103.herokuapp.com/) Click item, press "Delete" button and confirm.

Comment: <button ng-click="delete(item)" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Yes</button>
      <a ng-click="delete(item)" href="" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Yes2</a>

Comment: $scope.delete = function() {
     $state.go('table');
    };